# How to keep CAShapeLayer to be inside its parent UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bounds, cashapelayer

I have a Custom UIView, creating a line, which is rotating in around its own axis.

```
lineLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)/2.0f;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)/2.0f;
CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(width, height);

CGPoint addLineToPoint = CGPointMake(width, -30);

[bezierPath moveToPoint:centerPoint];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:addLineToPoint];

lineLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

lineLayer.frame = self.bounds;
lineLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;

lineLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;

[self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];

[lineLayer setHidden:YES];
```

Now This View is set as PARENT CLASS of a UIView in Storyboard.

When I run Project, this linelayer is seen out of its parent View's Layer.

[image]

Here in this image, lineLayer is coming out of its parent UIView's and also another View is parent View in storyboard heirarchy.

Any help????

Comment: I think its because of this `lineLayer.frame = self.bounds;` your frame is bigger, change the height of the frame it should work.

Comment: you mean frame of lineLayer or View?

Comment: Yes the frame you are setting is of View, it can be bigger than the actual drawing, so instead of setting the `self.bounds` you could try change the height comes from `self.bounds`?

Comment: I am setting self.bounds because I want this to rotate around its own axis/center. else it will lose its center position. So, any other idea

Comment: How about using a mask layer ( with visible area like you want ) in front of.

Comment: I can do that, but issue is that , I don't know how to apply mask layer when layer is needle comes to down side, as I want big length from right side, but not from left or down side.....

Comment: @anhtu, so, what do you say, how can we achive it using masking?

Comment: I mean that mask layer for superview of `lineLayer `, not for lineLayer. E.g. mask layer with frame like "gray rectangle"

Comment: It is subClass of UIView, so you want that mask layer of that UIView, where this lineLayer exists?

Comment: with self of `[self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];` . E.g. `self.layer.mask = maskshape;`

Comment: where maskshape is ShaperLayer or simply UIView?

Comment: maskshape is CAShapeLayer with UIBezierPath

Comment: Okay, i do try, but I think this will disturb my own view. let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

> *CGPoint addLineToPoint = CGPointMake(width, -30);*

with

```
CGPoint addLineToPoint = CGPointMake(width, -height);
```

Comment: No use. Same thing, even height of line increased. @Shebin

Comment: I know it I will make it zero instead of -height, it will become smaller in length, but its not useful, I want big line which gets cut when line comes to boundries of view